# Raspberry PI Debian multiple network interfaces WiFi and LAN

Tags: networking, wifi

I have an PI2 with an USB WiFi adapter, and want to set it up with both wifi and fallback to LAN cable, but can't make it work.

Is there something wrong with my setup... When I boot with the LAN cable attached, it works great, with both interfaces, wired, also when i detach the LAN cable, the wifi works fine.. But if i boot without LAN cable, it will not bring up the wlan0 interface ..

File: /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.0.14
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1

auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.0.15
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-nameservers 192.168.0.1
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

Comment: Are you actually using Debian or Raspbian? You have nothing that will react to network changes. You could make this outdated and incomplete setup work, but I suggest you see http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697